# TSQL - openxml decodes a xml element with encoded value

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to stop SQL Server 2008 from decoding the XML element values if they happen to be encoded?

For example I have the following query:

```
declare @T nvarchar(max)
SET @T = '<node><val>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;</val></node>'

declare @doc nvarchar(max), @idoc int
SET @doc = @T

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @doc;

select * from openxml (@idoc, '//*')

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

Once executed the value of `<val>` ends up being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

where as it should remain as

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. By using entities such as `&lt;` you are simply encoding those values for storage in the XML node. You are storing `<` but representing it as `&lt;` as not to confuse the XML parser. When it's output it's decoded by default.

If you want the encoded values in your output you must either double encode:

```
declare @T nvarchar(max)
SET @T = '<node><val>&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;</val></node>'

declare @doc nvarchar(max), @idoc int
SET @doc = @T

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @doc;

select * from openxml (@idoc, '//*')

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

Or you can wrap your encoded xml value is a [CDATA block](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

```
declare @T nvarchar(max)
SET @T = '<node><val><![CDATA[&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;]]></val></node>'

declare @doc nvarchar(max), @idoc int
SET @doc = @T

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @doc;

select * from openxml (@idoc, '//*')

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML data type and cast the result of `query()` to `nvarchar(max)`.

```sql
declare @X xml 
set @X = '<node><val>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;</val></node>'
select cast(@X.query('/node/val/text()') as nvarchar(max))
```

Result

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
```